# How to keep search value in unity dashboard during changing lenses?

Tags: 14.04, unity, unity-dash, search, lenses

If I go to the unity dashboard and search for something, the search value is not available on other lenses.

[image: How to keep search value in unity dashboard during changing lenses?]